# How to limit the standart library thread count?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I want to limit the number of thread for a given job.
Here is a sample code of my attempts to do so:

```
 #DEFINE MAX_THREAD_COUNT 5
```

Later:

```
void MyClass::a_method() {
    unsigned thread_count = 0;
    std::vector<std::thread> jobs;

    std::vector<AnObject> collection;

    for(auto& c : collection) {
        if(thread_count >= MAX_THREAD_COUNT) {
            for(auto& j : jobs) {
                if(j.joinable()) {
                    j.join();
                    thread_count--;
                }
            }  
        }
        thread_count++;
        jobs.push_back(std::thread([=] { this->a_long_job(c); }));
    }

    for(auto& j : jobs) {
        if(j.joinable()) {
            j.join();
        }
    } 
}
```

The problem is that sometimes `this->a_long_job` isn't call all the time, I checked this by printing a line inside the method and by printing the number of elements contained in `collection`.

Another idea that could work but isn't elegant would be to launch `max_thread` threads with `c/max_thread` calls of `this->a_long_job(c)` in each.

I don't think that I need a thread pool for this application because there's a need only in this method.

Notes:

- No external libraries
- C++11 and further

Comment: `thread_count` is uninitialized. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an uninitialized object.

Comment: What's `t`, and how, if at all, is it related to `jobs`? It would be best if you prepare and show [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I've corrected my post sorry for the mistakes, it was supposed to be posted like this.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code you've shown (apart from the fact that `collection` is empty; I assume it's not in your real code). To the extent there is a problem, it must lie in the code you haven't shown. Once again, prepare a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Yours is lacking the Complete part.

Comment: My question is more about can I limit threads in this way rather than asking is this code is correct, that's why I don't prepare a MCVE. It could have been posted in language agnostic. Sorry for the laborious corrections needed though.

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell, this code would not create more than `MAX_THREAD_COUNT` threads running simultaneously. If that's what you are asking. You did say, however, that *"sometimes `this->a_long_job` isn't call all the time"* Are you no longer interested in investigating this part?

Comment: Your idea cannot possibly work because your thread0 might be running 10 times longer thhread1..thread4 and you will waste time waiting for it while all other threads have finished long ago. Just implement a thread pool and a job queue. Not that much work, really, and it's well understood and known to work.